# How do i call a string method into a jpanel

Tags: java, swing, class, for-loop, jpanel

How do i call a method string(printBestillingsordre) into another method and create a JPanel to it

```
public String printBestillingsordre(){
        JButton button = new JButton("Varemodtaget");
        String temp = "";
        for(HentbestillingsordreRegistrer hentboregistrer: hbor){
        if(status == "Leveret"){    

        temp += "Bestillings Status: " + hentboregistrer.BestillingsStatus+" \n" + 
        "LeverandoerID: "+ hentboregistrer.LeverandoerID+" \n";


        }else{
            temp += hentboregistrer.BestillingsStatus+ button + "\n" + 
                    "LeverandoerID: "+ hentboregistrer.LeverandoerID+" \n";
        }
        System.out.println(temp);

    }
        return temp;
}
```

into this code

```
public JPanel HentOrdreGUI(){

    JPanel info = new JPanel();
    info.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    info.add(printBestillingsordre());
    return null;
}
```

btw this code is long from done

Comment: 1) `public JPanel HentOrdreGUI()` Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  3) Instructive examples are a lot more instructive when they are in a language the audience understands.  Please use English based identifiers for attributes & methods.

Comment: Just so I understand your problem. The method printBestillingsordre() returns a String that you want to display onto a panel?? If so then you need to create a JLabel to represent the string.

Comment: why are you returning null from `HentOrdreGUI()`? did you check cworner1's answer?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to add visual text from "printBestillingsordre()" to a Panel, the easiest way is to change the line:

```
info.add(printBestillingsordre());
```

to

```
info.add(new JLabel(printBestillingsordre());
```

That will create a visual representative of your string. To organise your GUI components I would recommend looking at the following [link:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)